# Проверить наличие столбца в таблице, если есть, то получить из него данные

Tags: sql-server, select

Мне необходимо получать данные из таблиц SQL-сервера простым `SELECT`, однако, количество столбцов может различаться от таблице к таблице, например, столбец EqupId есть лишь в одной из просматриваемых мной таблиц.

Я пытался сделать вот так:

```
if COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('VS_OPC_Config'), 'EqupId', 'ColumnId') is null 
      SELECT ID FROM VS_OPC_Config
else 
      SELECT ID, EqupId FROM VS_OPC_Config
```

Если в таблице искомый столбец есть, то все проходит замечательно, а если нет запрос выдает ошибку "Недопустимое имя столбца". Т.е. насколько я понимаю, выполняется и то, что идет после `ELSE`. Как можно избежать этого? Или как лучше выполнить запрос, когда знаешь, что определенный столбец есть не во всех опрашиваемых таблицах? (Запрос желательно один)

Comment: exec ('SELECT ID, EqupId FROM VS_OPC_Config')

Comment: @Konst ошибка по-прежнему осталась

Comment: вы что-то не так сделали. вот рабочий код на моей базе if COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('UserClients'), 'ClientID', 'ColumnId') is null 
      exec ('SELECT UserID FROM dbo.UserClients');
else 
      exec ('SELECT UserID, ClientID FROM dbo.UserClients');

Comment: @Konst, Спасибо!

Comment: пометьте как ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу все было почти так как я сделал, но с небольшими уточнениями:

`if COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('VS_OPC_Config'), 'EqupId', 'ColumnId') is null 
exec ('SELECT ID FROM VS_OPC_Config');
else 
exec ('SELECT ID, EqupId FROM VS_OPC_Config');`
Спасибо @Konst за помощь!